# PowerShell is not using provided credentials

Tags: powershell, credentials

I created a PowerShell script that used to run fine with no problems. Now after the summer break, whenever i run the script, it asks for credentials to create a PSDrive.

```cs
$Source_Path = "\\192.168.1.32\Backup_Servers\EAVSRV01\WindowsImageBackup"
$Source_Username = "bcktest"
$Source_Password = "*****" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force


$Destination_Path = "\\192.168.1.34\Backup_Servers\EAVSRV01\Daily\"
$Destination_Username = "bcktest"
$Destination_Password = "*****" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force

#Creates the PSCredential, so we can login to servers, with the required credentials

$Source_Credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($Source_Username,$Source_Password)
$Destination_Credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($Destination_Username,$Destination_Password)



#Mount the paths as PSDrives, so they're easier to work with

New-PSDrive -Name DestinationDrive -PSProvider FileSystem -Root $Destination_Path -Credential $Destination_Credential
New-PSDrive -Name SourceDrive -PSProvider FileSystem -Root $Source_Path -Credential $Source_Credentials
```

When I try to create the PSDrive "DestinationDrive" it prompts for a username and password. If i press cancel, it still creates the PSDrive. 
When I try to create the PSDrive "SourceDrive" it doesn't prompt for the username or password. And it also creates the PSDrive.
The important part here is that it doesn't, prompt the user for anything.

Comment: Something to note: I would not leave your password in plaintext in your file.  If this is running on one system (as I suspect), use `Read-Host -AsSecureString | ConvertFrom-SecureString` and take that output to assign to `$Destination_Password = output | ConvertTo-SecureString`.  I'll post an example of what I use as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo in your code. The credential that you are passing for creating your destination drive is called `$Destination_Credential`, but the credential you are defining previously is called `$Destination_Credentials` - note carefully the difference!

Please check your code before posting on StackOverflow; simple typographical errors are reasons for closing a question.